# Allow tags that don't exist yet to be used in the StackExchange™ GlobalTag MegaBlender™

Tags: feature-request, tag-filters

I've been trying to keep up with Jin's new design questions on the various beta StackExchange sites [using the StackExchange™ GlobalTag MegaBlender™](https://stackexchange.com/tagsets/37/design), but I've hit a snag — the MegaBlender™ doesn't allow me to add sites where there are no questions tagged [design](/questions/tagged/design) yet.

This means that I have to constantly update the tag set, which is annoying, and somewhat defeats the purpose of actually using the MegaBlender™. Can we be allowed to include tags from sites where no question with that tag exists yet?

Comment: What about [design] and checking *All Sites*?

Comment: @rchern Won't work - SO already has 4k+ `[design]` questions, Programmers and UI have lots more, and when Graphics Design launches this would be truly useless - I want to see those from the Meta sites only

Comment: Yeah, I've always wondered why we have "All Sites" but not "All Metas". That would not just fix your problem, but also greatly reduce the clutter on the "popular tag sets" tab.

Comment: Back to your actual question, as a workaround, try using [this tag set](http://stackexchange.com/tagsets/48/) ([featured] questions on all metas). I've added it to my tag sets just a few days ago, and it was thanks to it that I've noticed Jin's design suggestions for CSTheory and RPG.

Comment: @RegDwight - We have all metas now.  However, we still don't support your use case [or mine](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/90289/excluding-a-set-of-sites-from-a-filter), I'm thinking about setting up a bounty.  Do you mind if I add your use case to that post, and put the bounty there?