# Excluding a set of sites from a filter

Tags: feature-request, tag-filters

### My problem / use case:

I'd like to know when someone creates a question with the a certain tag on the StackExchange network, so that I can (1) answer the question, or, if necessary, (2) advocate that the question be migrated to a more appropriate site/closed as a duplicate of a question on another site.  For instance, if I monitored the [electronics](/questions/tagged/electronics) tag, I could answer [this question on Bicycles.SE](https://bicycles.stackexchange.com/questions/3282/cheap-energy-sources-for-electronics-during-touring-with-low-amount-of-sun-energy).  I have no idea if, say, Cooking.SE will tomorrow have a question by someone with a burned-out food processor.

The filters/tag sets and associated feeds are a great tool to solve this problem.  However, many of the related tags that I'd like to filter are heavily represented on Electronics Design, which I monitor differently.  Therefore, I need to exclude Electronics Design from the filter.

### Why the current site doesn't solve my problem:

Currently, if I select a set of sites (not including Electronics Design) on the [filters page](https://stackexchange.com/filters), and then type in a tag name, *any sites which don't currently use that flag are eliminated from the selection.*  This is a neat feature for some use cases, but it makes it impossible to exclude a single site (or small group of sites) from a filter.

### Proposed new feature:

I'd prefer to have a third radio button in the list:

> I'd like to include...

> > ( ) All Questions
> > (o) Just questions tagged  [______]

> on....

> > ( ) All sites
> > (o) All sites except: [______] (+ checkboxes below)
> > ( ) Just these sites: [______] (+ checkboxes below)

over simply eliminating the feature which limits "Just these sites" to sites which currently have the tag, because then I could catch new questions on sites which haven't been created yet.

Can we change the filters page so that a site (or set of sites) can be excluded from the filter?

Comment: Why can't you simply do "Just these sites" and select all but Electronics?

Comment: @Rebecca - Because then I would miss sites which later create the tag.  For instance, two weeks ago, Bicycles.SE didn't appear in the list because that question hadn't been asked yet.

Comment: Ahhhh, ok. I see.  The wording in your post confused me, sorry.

Comment: Alternatively, selecting a tag could not limit to showing sites where the tag currently exists.

Comment: @Rebecca - Any ideas on how I could improve the wording?  I understand what I meant, but that doesn't mean it makes sense...

Comment: @Rebecca - That was the other (less preferred) option.  I tried to use your wording to clarify.

Comment: Makes sense, +1. (:

Comment: Eliminating certain sites from a filter would be very useful, especially now that there are language specific sites for Portuguese and Japanese. I would like to see all questions tagged with `Excel` but not if they are from the Portuguese or Japanese site, because I don't speak these languages.

Comment: See [this meta.steckowerflow question](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/283238/sub-domain-ja-stackoverflow-com-content-appearing-in-stackoverflow-filtered-ques?cb=1), to understand @teylyn

Comment: This would be really nice to have. Plus, the way you are suggesting it be used would increase answer quality across all sites.  Win, win!